# config nginx redirect connection to MQTT Broker

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, mqtt, reverse-proxy, mosquitto

I have an Issue to Acces MQTT mosquitto Broker over an Nginx Container
This is My docker Compose :

```
`version: '3.8'
services:
  mqtt-broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.13
    container_name: mqtt-broker
    user: "1000:1000"
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - ./config/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.:ro

  mqtt-nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: mqtt-nginx
    ports:
      - '1884:1884'
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-broker
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`
```

this is my nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
stream {
  server {
    listen 1884;
      proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1883;
        }
}
```

but when i test the connection with :
`mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1884 -t mytopic` 
i get a network protocol error :
`Error: A network protocol error occurred when communicating with the broker.`

Any idea how to Fix my config !!

Comment: change `127.0.0.1` to `{your_localserver_ip}`, and try again

Answer (score 1):

fixed nginx config :

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {
  upstream mqtt_broker {
    server mqtt-broker:1883;
  }

  server {
    listen 1884;
    proxy_pass mqtt_broker;
  }
}
```

and Add Network in my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mqtt-broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.13
    container_name: mqtt-broker
    user: "1000:1000"
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    networks:
      mqtt-net:

  volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      mqtt-net:

networks:
  mqtt-net:
```

Comment: The important part of this change is that `127.0.0.1` will always point to the loopback interface of which ever container the code is running in, so in this case it points to the nginx container, **NOT** the host machine the containers are running on. Where as after the change you are using the container's name which docker will resolve to the right IP address.